# Arduino serial non-blocking

Tags: c, rs485

I'm writing an Arduino program to communicate with another module using RS485, so I need to control data flow with one pin. But when I set the pin to HIGH (line 88) it almost instantly falls (as you can see in the image, line 70). So my guess is that Arduino Serial.write() function is non-blocking, but I need it to be blocking [image]so the flow control pin stays high during whole packet transmit. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the code as text rather than image. And indent it by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button. It makes things easier for those who want to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You are right: `Serial.write()` is non blocking: it puts the data in a
buffer and waits for an interrupt routine to send it through the UART.
If you want to wait for the transmission to complete, you can call
`Serial.flush()`.